# What type of hose do I need to replace a pull out faucet?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The flexible line on my kitchen faucet seems to be leaking and plumbing is not my strong point!  The faucet is an american standard (not sure the model).  I'm wondering what type of hose to get for a replacement as I cant seem to find the exact one and whether the bottom part of that copper piece just unscrews?

[image]

Comment: You might have to contact the manufacturer, and purchase [replacement parts](http://www.americanstandard-us.com/store/repair-parts/) from them.

Comment: Where is it leaking from? At the flexible hose connection, copper connection, at where the hose connects to the fitting?

Comment: It seems to be leaking out of the flexible hose itself.  I dont see or feel any water further up.

Answer (score 1):

Unbolt at the section you've highlighted (yes, it should just unbolt), remove the weight, and bring the whole pull-out to the hardware store to ensure your replacement matches.